# Is it possible to transfer array with data to another component by react-redux in HOC

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I may be missing something, but I can't find any example how to pass array with data from HOC component to another component.
Here is my code

```js
import React from 'react'
import NoAccessPage from '../../pages/Admin/NoAccess';
import { menuItems } from '../../config/menu';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const AuthorizationHOC = (access) =>{
  (WrappedComponent) =>
   class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props)

      this.state = {
        user: {
            accessItems: [
              'reseptionPointsAccess',
              'servicesAccess'
            ]
        }
      }
    }

    render() {
        const { accessItems } = this.state.user;

        let menuAccess = [];

        menuItems.forEach(item => {
            if (accessItems.includes(item.access)) {
                menuAccess.push(item)
            }
        })

        return (
            <div>
                {accessItems.includes(access) ? <WrappedComponent {...this.props} /> : <NoAccessPage/> }
            </div>
        )
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        menuArray: state
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(AuthorizationHOC)
```

I would like to pass array `menuAccess` to another component, but I can't wrap `AuthorizationHOC` by connect.

In console I received

```
Cannot call a class as a function
```

Comment: do you want to pass menuAccess or menuArray, and do you want to pass it to WrappedComponent or NoAccessPage

Comment: I would like to pass it to another component, Passing it to WrappedComponent, or NoAccess component will be easy

Comment: What relation does this other component have with your hoc why can you just connect that compoment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the HOC with connect, what you need is to wrap the returned component with connect

```
import React from 'react'
import NoAccessPage from '../../pages/Admin/NoAccess';
import { menuItems } from '../../config/menu';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const AuthorizationHOC = (access) =>{
  (WrappedComponent) => {
     class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
          user: {
              accessItems: [
                'reseptionPointsAccess',
                'servicesAccess'
              ]
          }
        }
      }

      render() {
          const { accessItems } = this.state.user;

          let menuAccess = [];

          menuItems.forEach(item => {
              if (accessItems.includes(item.access)) {
                  menuAccess.push(item)
              }
          })

          return (
              <div>
                  {accessItems.includes(access) ? <WrappedComponent {...this.props} /> : <NoAccessPage/> }
              </div>
          )
      }
    }
    return connect(mapStateToProps)(WithAuthorization);
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        menuArray: state
    }
}

export default AuthorizationHOC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I have tried to use this code, and now I have got this error in console:

```js
(0 , _AuthorizationHOC2.default)(...) is not a function
```

This error shows up during rendering my HOC

```js
<Route path="/link" exact component={AuthorizationHOC('listOfOrdersAccess')(ListOfOrders)} />
```